# How to animate different parts of a robot arm

Tags: animation, parent

I am trying to make a robot arm.

I am able to add animation to one of the objects easily, but then whenever I try to add animation to other objects there is distortion in the first animation.

*What I tried:*

1. I have used parent relation but somehow changes in the child are effecting the animation of the parent.
2. I tried using bones and armature but exporting that as a *.glb* file is giving another time, all the animations and figures are getting distorted.

Is there a better way to do it?
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Please, upload some images to your post to better illustrate your question.

Comment: Just done, and 1 more question can we add and remove parent and child relation at different key frames?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not the right way of using blender, turns out you need to animate all the objecst in a single frame and then you can make subclips based on what clips you want, this can be done using three.js [Utilities](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/animation/AnimationUtils)